# Change displayer option in rtconner/laravel-tagging config file

Tags: php, laravel, config

I have a problem with https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging and could use some help.

Problem is that my tag names get altered before saving to db.

Tag.php model has mutator (don't want to change because its in vendor directory)

```
public function setNameAttribute($value)
{
    $displayer = config('tagging.displayer');
    $displayer = empty($displayer) ? '\Illuminate\Support\Str::title' : $displayer;

    $this->attributes['name'] = call_user_func($displayer, $value);
}
```

config/tagging.php has

```
'displayer' => '\Illuminate\Support\Str::title',
```

I don't want 'displayer' to use '\Illuminate\Support\Str::title' because it will make my tag name first letter capital ("echo" => "Echo") and remove other capital letters ("HeY" => "Hey").

What should I put for 'displayer' value?

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the config value accepts a function name, all you have to do is replace it with one that transforms a string the way you want it to.

If you want to do nothing, there's a function for that:

```
'displayer' => 'value'
```

> The `value` function returns the value it is given. (...)
>
> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-value